# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.stress.Stress

Tags: elassandra, cassandra-stress

How can I do a `cassandra-stress` on a `Elassandra` cluster?

cassandra-stress is not on elassandra file system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stress tool is located in $CASSANDRA_HOME/tools/bin

Prior to v6.2.3.11, there was a packaging issue with the stress tool. If you use an older version, you have to download it from the official Cassandra distribution.